# Does Google take any of my file data on Android?

Tags: sync, gallery, google

I read about syncing photos with Google on Android somewhere, and got a little concerned.
It is probably just a special Google service you have to sign up for, but just in case, I want to relieve me of this concern.

Does Google send my photos(files in the gallery) to their servers?

I under no circumstance would like automatic syncing of picture and photo files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Google supports photo syncing, but you can disable this.

- If you have Google+ installed, disable Auto Backup. Open the app's settings, and go to `Auto Backup > OFF`.
- Disable Google photo sync. On your phone's settings, go to `System settings > Accounts > Google > username@gmail.com > Sync Picasa Web albums`. Make sure sync is disabled.

**UPDATE 2013-11-22:** As per [Damien Golding](https://android.stackexchange.com/users/46527/damien-golding), it is also worth noting that the settings of the camera must be checked. In his case, Google photo sync was **ON** in the `Albums` setting.

Comment: Thanks. You're right, my photos and videos are automatically backed up : /
Don't are about photos I publicly show, but photos I privately take with my Nexus camera are sent? Surely that is pushing the boundaries.

Comment: @DamienGolding Try to check your camera's settings if it also has a setting to share the picture you take. Disable that. Then, please don't forget to upvote and accept the answer if it has helped you. :)

Comment: Thanks, the settings can actually be found from the "Albums" Settings page.
"Google photo sync is on" : /

Comment: The second setting you mention doesn't automatically upload photos. It *downloads* pictures that are *already* in Picasa (the old Google photo service) so you can see them on the device.